Apache Iceberg with .NET for AWS S3 Tables
We are looking to test out the new AWS S3 Table features with our existing .NET application.  Currently we are outputting Parquet files utilizing the NuGet package Parquet.NET  to produce those files/objects for our S3 bucket.
With the S3 Tables feature, the documentation seems like you need to interact with the service/table endpoint using an Iceberg client and push the data directly to the endpoint; as opposed to putting an object to the bucket.  We are having trouble finding an existing library with this type of functionality/compatibility for .NET to test out this promising looking feature.
